# Detect if a RichTextBox is empty

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

What is the best way to detect if a WPF RichTextBox/FlowDocument is empty?

The following works if only text is present in the document. Not if it contains UIElement's

```
new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, Document.ContentEnd).IsEmpty
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could compare the pointers, which is not all too reliable:

```
var start = rtb.Document.ContentStart;
var end = rtb.Document.ContentEnd;
int difference = start.GetOffsetToPosition(end);
```

This evaluates to `2` if the RTB is loaded, and `4` if content has been entered and removed again.
If the RTB is completely cleared out e.g. via `select all -> delete` the value will be `0`.

---

In the [Silverlight reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.contentstart.aspx) another method is found which can be adapted and improved to:

```
public bool IsRichTextBoxEmpty(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    if (rtb.Document.Blocks.Count == 0) return true;
    TextPointer startPointer = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    TextPointer endPointer = rtb.Document.ContentEnd.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
    return startPointer.CompareTo(endPointer) == 0;
}
```

Comment: The count is one even if the RichTextBox is empty.

Comment: I edited my answer to show another approach, it is a bit odd though.

Comment: The first 3 lines worked for me. Thanks! Even if there is a single space left, you wouldn't get the difference as 0.

Comment: I was hoping to end up with something like empty== count<=4 .. but sadly, if you paste an image into a freshly cleared rtb it yields 3.

Answer (score 3):

H.B.'s answer isn't useful if you need to distinguish between images and whitespace.  You can use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33428543/1001985) to check for images.

```
bool IsEmpty(Document document)
{
    string text = new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, Document.ContentEnd).Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) == false)
        return false;
    else
    {
        if (document.Blocks.OfType<BlockUIContainer>()
            .Select(c => c.Child).OfType<Image>()
            .Any())
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This seems laborious, and still probably isn't correct for all scenarios.  But I couldn't find any better way.

Comment: This is *very* expensive because it renders the document as a new string every time

Answer (score 2):

The answer above works if you don't put anything into the RTB. However, if you simply delete the contents, the RTB tends to return a single, empty paragraph, not a completely empty string. So, this is more reliable in such cases:

```
string text = new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, Document.ContentEnd).Text;
return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text);
```

This only applies to textual contents, of course.

Answer (score 0):

First - thank you to McGarnagle - their answer got me going in the right direction.  However for whatever reason their image check didn't work for me.  This is what I ended up doing:

```
    Private Function RichTextBoxIsEmpty(BYVAL rtb As RichTextBox) As Boolean

    Dim ReturnCode As Boolean = True

    Dim text As String = New TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd).Text

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) Then

        For Each block As Block In rtb.Document.Blocks

            'check for an image
            If TypeOf block Is Paragraph Then
                Dim paragraph As Paragraph = DirectCast(block, Paragraph)
                For Each inline As Inline In paragraph.Inlines
                    If TypeOf inline Is InlineUIContainer Then
                        Dim uiContainer As InlineUIContainer = DirectCast(inline, InlineUIContainer)
                        If TypeOf uiContainer.Child Is Image Then
                            ReturnCode = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            ' Check for a table
            If TypeOf block Is Table Then
                ReturnCode = False
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

    Else

        ReturnCode = False

    End If

    Return ReturnCode

End Function
```

there may be other checks to do, but this at least covers text, images and tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension of H.B.'s idea that works with both **text and images**.

I found that difference is always >4 whenever the RTB has text.  However, if you only paste an image it is 3.  To combat this i look at the string length of the raw rtf string.

```
var start = Document.ContentStart;
var end = Document.ContentEnd;
var difference = start.GetOffsetToPosition(end);

HasText = difference > 4 || GetRtfText().Length > 350;


public string GetRtfText()
{
  var tr = new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, Document.ContentEnd);
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
    return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
  }
}
```

Through my testing i found that an empty box with no chars has a length of 270.  If i even paste in an image that's only 1 pixel in size it balloons to 406.

I played with toggling on various formatting options without typing any letters and haven't gotten close to 300, so I went with 350 for the baseline.

The length check could be expensive if there are no textual characters, but they pasted in a massive image.