# C# WPF RichTextboxf check if there is any Text

Tags: c#, wpf

I wan´t to check a **RichTextbox** for content or better if it is empty.
I debugged through the code and found that in the string i get from the box there is "\r\n". How can I check for this, because simply `String.Equals("\r\n");` don´t work. For getting the text out of the *RichTextbox* I have this method:

```
 private string ConvertRichTextBoxContentsToString(RichTextBox rtb)
  {
        TextRange textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart,
        rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
        return textRange.Text;
  }
```

Has anyone an idea for this?

Comment: What if you try to compare to Environment.NewLine: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: is `" "` also empty string for you?

Comment: You could check for `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` if you don't care about other types of white-space as well.

Comment: @Only3lue `textRange.Text.Trim().Length==0` will verify that there is no text since `Trim()` removes all leading and trailing occurrences and `\r\n` being a CRLF new line character will be removed, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` should actually work. Try this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string s = ConvertRichTextBoxContentsToString(rtb);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("empty!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtb" />
```

This works as well:

```
string s = ConvertRichTextBoxContentsToString(rtb);
if(s == "\r\n")
{
    MessageBox.Show("empty!");
}
```

And Equals as well:

```
string s = ConvertRichTextBoxContentsToString(rtb);
if (s.Equals("\r\n"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("empty!");
}
```

If you don't see the MessageBox the RichTextBox is not truly empty. You may want to read this:

[Detect if a RichTextBox is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825575/detect-if-a-richtextbox-is-empty)

If content has been entered and removed the difference between the start and end pointers is 4. You may try to use the following method from above to determine whether the RichTextBox is empty:

```
public bool IsRichTextBoxEmpty(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    if (rtb.Document.Blocks.Count == 0) return true;
    TextPointer startPointer = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    TextPointer endPointer = rtb.Document.ContentEnd.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
    return startPointer.CompareTo(endPointer) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

\r\n are the CRLF new line characters

have you tried the .IsEmpty property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn´t work, because I can see that the .Text or the String itself is "/r/n". But I don´t understand why then it doesn´t work just with Equals.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
 {
    // Text found
 }
 else
 {
     // No text
 }
```

You can also get rid of whitspaces and new lines with `text.Trim()`

Comment: I tried your solutions but non of them works, because I can see that the .Text or the String itself is "/r/n". But I don´t understand why then it doesn´t work just with Equals.