# Why an empty RichtTextBox has "\r\n" as text?

Tags: c#, string, wpf, richtextbox

This is a text editor. I am trying to open a new file and if the existing file is not empty, users get a warning to save the file or not. But if I use the condition `if (text== "")`, the value of text still has `"\r\n"` new line value. Even I didn't click on the text area.
Why does string get the value of the new line? It doesn't have to be empty?

```cs
private void New_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = new TextRange(richtxtbox.Document.ContentStart, richtxtbox.Document.ContentEnd).Text; 

    if (text == "")
    {
        MainWindow newWindow = new MainWindow();
        newWindow.Show();
        Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
    }
    else
    {
        // ...       
    }
}
```

I have to do this:

```cs
if (text == "" || text == "\r\n")
{
    MainWindow newWindow = new MainWindow();
    newWindow.Show();
    Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
}
```

Comment: Use [TextRange.IsEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textrange.isempty?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to check if a range is empty or not.

Comment: Using `TextRange.Text` is an expensive operation that [creates and returns a new string on each call](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Documents/TextRangeBase.cs,676) and shouldn't be called frequently

Comment: Did you copy the code [from this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825575/detect-if-a-richtextbox-is-empty) Using a TextRange just to check whether the document is empty is very wasteful

Comment: I declare Richtextbox without FlowDocument. I have added FlowDocument to Richtextbox. it works.  TextRange.IsEmpty returns true but without FlowDocument returns false. @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote:

> I am trying to open a new file and if the existing file is not empty...

What do you mean ***"the existing file is not empty"***? I guess you mean the current content of the `RichtextBox`, that actually is container for the `FlowDocument` object. Right?

Result of the `var text = new TextRange(richtxtbox.Document.ContentStart, richtxtbox.Document.ContentEnd).Text` depend on content of the `FlowDocument`.

If you declare `RichTextBox` as below than `text` will contain `"\r\n"`. It's because the `FlowDocument` will contain one `Paragraph` block. And when this paragraph is converted to text it will automatically appended with the `Environment.NewLine`.

```xml
<RichTextBox Name="richtxtbox">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>          
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

But if you declare `RichTextBox` as empty `FlowDocument` than `text` will be empty - it contains `0` blocks.

```xml
<RichTextBox Name="richtxtbox">
    <FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

For more information read the following article: [RichTextBox Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: TextRange has an `IsEmpty` property that's far cheaper than creating a new string with the serialized contents every time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: In the case when the document contains an empty paragraph (visually it looks like an empty document) the `TextRange.IsEmpty` will return `false` and  this will confuse the user. Therefore call the `IsEmpty` will not help a much.

Comment: The question here is whether the control is empty or not. Right now, it's not. A single empty paragraph is still a paragraph. If the TextRange is only used to get the text ... it shouldn't be used in the first place

Comment: Yes, I mean the current content of the RichtextBox. I think I found the problem, I used RichtextBox without FlowDocument.
`
<RichTextBox Grid.Row="2"
     x:Name="richtxtbox" 
     SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged_Click">
 </RichTextBox>

`  @Victor

Comment: @Kalo: Actually, you don't need to explicitly create the `FlowDocument` object.  The `RichTextBox` has parameterless constructor that creates implicit instance of a `FlowDocument` as its initial content. And the initial document will contain one `Paragraph` with an empty `Run` in it. You can see this in the sources here: [https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/RichTextBox.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/RichTextBox.cs)