# C# Chat - how to show messages decently?

Tags: c#, winforms

im making a Chat client and server.. everything was for the best, thread, connections, all ok.

But now my C# program got a problem.. 
..i searched for hours and days without solution

Its my problem:

I need to replace the (classic) textbox for reading, with something that supports *color*, *smile*, *font*, maybe *interactive features*.

**RichTextBox**? No *GIF* support or interactive items

i like **fastcoloredtextbox** but cant change font or font-size (it's possible but does not work well) btw not right for me

*I would use a Browser*, which allows me to use html, css and javascript, so to solve all my problems..

Why i cant?

Geckofx? Don't work [!?] :|

Standard **WebBrowser** suck. I had Windows 8, but still IE9 (wtf?).

**Awesomium**? It's ok but can't modify the document... 
should i create a blank html page and insert all through javascript?

any solution? what do you suggest?

[it's a desktop app, i'm using vs2010]

thanks

**EDIT:** Got a solution.

***WebSockets*** is the way..! :3

Comment: This is a desktop app?

Comment: Winforms?  WPF? Something else?

Comment: @TheTrigger You need WPF.

Comment: WebBrowser seems to be the best but i don't know how you can handle win 8 issue.

Comment: @Thetrigger because winforms is a dinosaur, and doesnt' support anything. You will not get a `decent` UI from winforms. I can imitate the behavior of Windows Live Messenger with a simple WPF ListBox and a couple of DataTemplates. winforms doesn't support that without resorting to a bunch of horrible hacks.

Comment: thanks, looking on web for infos.
any tips for me?

Comment: @TheTrigger the best advice I can give is `Use WPF and MVVM` - don't try to code the UI yourself. Create the proper data and `DataTemplates` and let the UI draw itself. It's much simpler that way.

Comment: You would want to use WPF because it has a lot of flexibility with the XAML.  It will allow more flexibility in the overall design.

Comment: I would go with some of the c# realtime frameworks if I was you,Xsockets.net , fleck or superwebsocket

Answer (score 0):

I found a few links that could be useful if you want to use rtf:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/fe9bfcb7-b226-4a54-9882-11c699bf1cb4/
- [How can I make a hyperlink work in a RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435607/c-sharp-how-can-i-make-a-hyperlink-work-in-a-richtextbox)
- [C# / WPF: Richtextbox: Find all Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404516/c-sharp-wpf-richtextbox-find-all-images)

But there are many possible answers to this question, so its really up to you how you want to display the messages.